# Why is anaconda taking too much space (>30GB)?

Tags: anaconda

[image]

I ran

```
conda clean -all
```

That removed about 10GB and I still have 30GB usage.

I checked anaconda directory and found that the env folder takes about 20gb and packages folder took another 10gb.

Why is anaconda taking too much space? Each env takes about 3gb and I have 7 envs.

```
jupyter
matplotlib
image
keras_tqdm
opencv
msgpack-rpc-python
pandas
numpy
scipy
tensorflow-gpu
keras
h5py
```

That's one environment's requirements that takes up about 3GB.

Many thanks in advance.